# Compare user input with attribute within class in Ruby

Tags: ruby, compare

I am Ruby beginner and I have a question. I am writing this code - Dungeon adventure and I would like to use user input (which is converted to symbol)and check weather dungeon symbol reference (:west) exists. If it exists it should go based on user input (for example east).

My problem is that I do not know how to compare user input (y) with existing references (:west, :east, :south:, :north)

Thank you in advance.

```
class Dungeon
    attr_accessor :player
    def initialize(player)
        @player = player
        @rooms = {}
    end
    def add_room(reference, name, description, connections)
        @rooms[reference] = Room.new(reference, name, description, connections)
    end
    def start(location)
        @player.location = location
        show_current_description
    end
    def show_current_description
        puts find_room_in_dungeon(@player.location).full_description
    end
    def find_room_in_dungeon(reference)
        @rooms[reference]
    end
    def find_room_in_direction(direction)
        find_room_in_dungeon(@player.location).connections[direction]
    end
    def go(direction)
        puts "You go " + direction.to_s
        @player.location = find_room_in_direction(direction)
        show_current_description
    end
end

class Player
    attr_accessor :name, :location
    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
    end
end

class Room
    attr_accessor :reference, :name, :description, :connections
    def initialize(reference, name, description, connections)
        @reference = reference
        @name = name
        @description = description
        @connections = connections
    end
    def full_description
        @name + "\n\nYou are in " + @description
    end
end
 puts "What is your name?"

x = gets.chomp

player = Player.new(x)
puts "Hi #{x}. Welcome to adventure!"

my_dungeon = Dungeon.new(player)
# Add rooms to the dungeon
my_dungeon.add_room(:largecave, "Large Cave", "a large cavernous cave", { :west => :smallcave, :south => :coldcave, :north => :hotcave})
my_dungeon.add_room(:smallcave, "Small Cave", "a small, claustrophobic cave", { :east => :largecave, :south => :coldcave, :north => :hotcave })
my_dungeon.add_room(:coldcave, "Cold Cave", "a cold, icy cave", { :north => :hotcave })
my_dungeon.add_room(:hotcave, "Hot Cave", "a hot, very hot cave", { :south => :coldcave })
# Start the dungeon by placing the player in the large cave
my_dungeon.start(:largecave)

puts "Where would you like to go? west, north or south?"

y = gets.chomp.to_sym

#Here is the problem that I am not able to solve:

case y
    when y == Room::reference then my_dungeon.go(y)
    else  puts "There is no cave there" 
end
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried?  Just posting all your code will only make it more difficult for us to help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have access to all of your rooms and find which one has that symbol.  You do not need a case statement for this, you should be able to verify that it is one of the valid rooms, and then send it:

```ruby
if(my_dungeon.rooms[y])
  my_dungeon.go(y)
else
  puts "There is no cave there"
end
```

This is testing if `rooms[y]` is truthy (doesn't return a nil or false value).  When `y` doesn't exist, the hash (`my_dungeon.rooms`) will return `nil`.  That is a falsey value.

Comment: Thank you for writing to me. I inserted the code but I am getting an error http://prntscr.com/hxxg37

Comment: You need access to your `rooms`, so add in `attr_accessor :rooms` to your dungeon class.

Comment: Thank you, It works... I am learning Ruby less then a month so a lot of things are not clear to me. :)

I could not figure out this on my own...

Comment: Okay good! It’s good to practice. When you get the chance, choose my answer as the solution. Thanks!